# I'm confused with how to determine output probabilities and picking action in Policy Optimization

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm currently learning PPO for my game and got most basic down. I've watched several YouTube videos and tried to understand a couple codes but there's something that I'm confused of.

So, in my understanding, PPO (and maybe policy optimization in general) uses softmax as activation function to get the output as probability which then being inputted to gaussian distribution. From how I learn, all the output probabilities combined is supposed to be 1 which then implies that only one action being made. How this translates to something that may requires multiple action at the same time ? (Ex: pressing two or more button at the same time in game)

Do I need to map out all possible action? (Includes the combination)

Or did I miss something and that it is possible for the model to count output possiblity separately ? (Movement probabilities and Weapon action probabilities are different)

Comment: [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask this question. If you decide to ask it there, please, delete it from here, so that we avoid cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to map out all possible combination of actions if you are specifically wanting two actions to be taken at exactly the same time. At any given time step you can only pick one action from your output distribution so combinations would have to be included.

However, your agent could learn to alternate between shooting and moving but these actions would occur in different steps.